# How to get the query params inside getServerSideProps in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

My URL is something like this:

```
http://localhost:3000/success?merchant=xxxxxx&order_id=xxxxx&payment_ref_id=xxxxxxx&status=Aborted&status_code=9999&message=Not%20a%20Nagad%20account
```

I need to get the `payment_ref_id` from the URL inside `getServerSideProps`. How can I do that?
I tried something like `context.query.payment_ref_id` but didn't work.
My code :

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
    try {
        const payment_reference_id = context.query.payment_ref_id;
        const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/remote-payment-gateway-1.0/api/dfs/verify/payment/${payment_reference_id}`,
            {
                headers: {
                    "X-KM-IP-V4": IP_ADDRESS,
                    "X-KM-Client-Type": "PC_WEB",
                    "X-KM-Api-Version": "v-0.2.0",
                    "Content-Type": "application/json",
                }
            });

        const payment_verify_res = await response.data;
        const paymentStatus = await payment_verify_res.status;

        return {
            props: {
                StatusProps: payment_verify_res || null,
                PaymentStatus: paymentStatus || null,

            },


        }

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return { props: {} }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you log `context.query.payment_ref_id` when accessing the URL you provided, what do you see in the terminal?

Comment: @juliomalves undefined

Comment: Are the other query parameters `undefined` too? What does `context.query` return?

Comment: const { payment_ref_id } = context.query;
destructuring solved my problem

Answer (score 0):

This might sound silly, but check if you have this code in `/pages/success.tsx` or `/pages/success/index.tsx`
Also after getting the response you are not calling the `data()` method.
Your code should probably look something like this :

```js
const payment_verify_res = await response.data();
const paymentStatus = payment_verify_res.status;
```

Comment: Yes I am inside the success page